# Mostrar imagen en Java desde directorio del proyecto

Tags: java, jsf, eclipse, primefaces

Estoy haciendo un proyecto web con JSF y PrimeFaces. Cuando guardo una imagen en el directorio de mi proyecto y lo quiero usar en ese mismo instante, eclipse me muestra este error diciendo que no encuentra la ruta especificada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que actualizar la carpeta `fotosEmpleados` donde guardo mis fotos, dando click derecho sobre la carpeta y refresh y es cuando aparece la imagen que guardé como muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando yo doy click en mi botón mostrar, me guarda la imagen en el directorio mencionado, pero también lo quiero mostrar desde el directorio y ahí es donde me sale un error que dice que no encuentra la ruta especificada. Tengo que volver a refrescar la carpeta para que me reconozca que existe la imagen.

Comment: Haz intentado guardar la imagen en un directorio fuera del contexto de tu aplicación?

Comment: Gracias por comentar , si lo he intentado , y me sale el mismo error , el eclipse sale que no encuentra la ruta especificada , la verdad que ya tengo días buscando solución a este problema , pero bueno.

Comment: Y haz intentado desplegar tu proyecto en un contenedor externo al Eclipse? Te lo comento porque un recurso modificado/añadido/eliminado dentro del ambito de la aplicación debe ser resuelto con refresh o redeploy en algunos casos. La sugerencia del contenedor externo es porque manejo aplicaciones que descargan contenido pero en directorios externos y que están disponibles automáticamente para ser utilizados.

Comment: Tienes razon amigo , muchas gracias , acabo de ver referencias y tenias razon no es recomendable guardar las imagenes dentro de la aplicacion sino fuera de ella , por ejemplo ahora lo estoy guardando dentro de mi disco local C y ahora si funciona , pero no entiendo porque no desde mi aplicacion , utilizo apache tomcat 8 , al parecer se tendra que configurar algunas cosas , pero bueno .gracias amigo

Comment: Si, de nada colega. Recuerda que en el Tomcat realizas un `deploy` de tu aplicación, tu aplicación es un archivo .war (que viene a ser un .zip) al momento del deploy lo que hace el contendor es descomprimir el contenido de tu war en un directorio X desde donde van a estar disponibles los recursos de tu aplicación, al crear un contenido nuevo es requerido un "re despliegue", esto no es necesario cuando el contenido dinámico lo guardas fuera de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema no es de aplicación sino de Eclipse. Eclipse no reconoce automáticamente si se han creado archivos o carpetas dentro del proyecto que no hayan sido creadas por el IDE, a diferencia de un navegador de directorios de un sistema operativo (el clásico Mi PC de Windows, por ejemplo). No solo sucede con esto, otro caso similar es cuando actualizas tu repositorio local con los cambios del servidor (svn `update`, git `pull`, mercurial `pull` y `update`) y trae nuevos archivos, Eclipse tampoco los reconoce y tienes que refrescar las carpetas o el proyecto completo para que detecte estos nuevos archivos. Por ello, en Eclipse, es necesario refrescar la carpeta donde se han colocado los nuevos archivos.

Adicional a ello, lo mejor en el diseño de aplicaciones Web es no guardar los archivos cargados (uploaded) en una carpeta relativa a la aplicación. Es mejor crear una carpeta fuera del contexto de la aplicación web (quizás en `/opt/ruta/para/imagenes/de/webapp` u otro) y tener una mejor administración de estos recursos.